# Android Studio update and restart doesn't work

Tags: updates, android-studio

I use Android Studio 2.0.0. There's a new version 2.1.2 available. Every time I open Android Studio, I see a new update is available, and there is a option called update and restart.

When I click update and restart it downloads the update and automatically restart. But after restart I see the same message which I have done it couple of times but it remains same. Android studio simply doesn't update.

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The solution that worked for me is to start the Android Studio without any parameters. Please check this for details http://stackoverflow.com/a/30673777/4510869.

Answer (score 0):

Install android studio in your */home* partition and then update it via update and restart. It will definitely work then.

I was facing the same issue from couple of months. My android studio was installed in *opt* directory and that's the reason it wasn't getting updated even after downloading the update patch.

I installed android studio in one of the directory under my */home* partition and then put it on update, and voila... There it is, my updated latest Android Studio for me. :) Happy coding.